# How to detect objects with minimal weight?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking into a build where weight is very important and needs to be minimized (it flies). I want to be able to detect objects and path around them, using a raspi as the brain.  My first thought was perhaps a visual sensor like a webcam (would I need two of them for binocular vison?) -- the Kinect would be ideal, since it was designed to do depth detection, but it weighs 3 lbs!

What kind of hardware can I use to keep the weight of the entire build under a pound? Not looking for specific products necessarily, just a sense of what I'd need and if it's possible.

Comment: you will have better luck posting the question to http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious way to detect objects would be to use ultrasonic distance sensors.

[image: ultrasonic distance sensor]

These are light-weight (a few grams) and relatively inexpensive. (E.g. [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/172) sell a range of them for $25 each).

Answer (score 1):

RPi isn't a great choice for your "brain". It's not particularly energy efficient, so you need to lug extra batteries around/fly for less time.

You're probably better off to start with something like [this video development platform](https://estore.ti.com/TMDSVDP6437-DM6437-Digital-Video-Development-Platform-P1015.aspx) (of course it's a lot more expensive than a RPi though)